# How to display the value of the decorated @property on the html page?

Tags: django, properties, django-templates

I was asked to correct someone else's code. The man who wrote it, has long resigned. It seems to me that this should be done through the decorator @property.
I'm trying to use the decorator @property in django version 1.10:

Model:

```
class TblReestr(models.Model):
        id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
        ean13 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
        reg_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
        trade_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
        fabr_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
        reg_data = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
        mnn_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
        valuta_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
        num_prikaz = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)


        @property
        def current_price(self):
            surcharge = 0
            if (self.reg_price is None) or (self.reg_price == 0):
                return surcharge

            if self.reg_price < 50:
                surcharge = self.reg_price * 0.1173 + self.reg_price * 0.246
            elif 50 <= self.reg_price <= 500:
                surcharge = self.reg_price * 0.12 + self.reg_price * 0.249
            elif self.reg_price > 500:
              surcharge = self.reg_price * 0.1175 + self.reg_price * 0.243

            return self.reg_price + surcharge


        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'tbl_reestr'
```

But the data is not output to the html page:

```
{% elif target == 'reestr' %}
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table" onselectstart="return false">
    <thead>
        <tr class="info">
            <th class="text-center">Наименование</th>
            <th class="text-center">Производитель</th>
            <th class="text-center">Цена</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for item in item_list %}
        <tr class="active">
            <td>{{ item.trade_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.fabr_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ item.current_price }}</td> /* пустое */
            <td>{{ item.reg_price }}</td> /* есть  значение */
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

view.py:

```
    def search(request):
       q = request.GET['q']
       target = request.GET['target']
       title = request.GET['title']
       if target == 'brak':
           item_list = TblBrak.objects.filter(trade_name__icontains=q)
       elif target == 'reestr':
           item_list = TblReestr.objects.filter(trade_name__icontains=q)
```

Tell me plz how to display current_price on a page?

Comment: What do you mean by `But the data is not output to the html page:` ? Are the items not showing or just not the `item.current_price` part?

Comment: Sory for my bad english. I meant that the value (current_price) is not printed in the template. other items(item.trade_name,item.fabr_name,  item.reg_price) showing at the templates(html page), but item.current_price is not showing.

Comment: Django templates ignore all errors. Try `print(item_list.first())` in your view to see if any errors happen.

Comment: I suspect a TypeError, because [Decimals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) and regular Python floats don't mix very well.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `print(item_list.first().current_price)`

Comment: if i use such as (surcharge = self.reg_price * 11.73/100 + self.reg_price * 24.6/100). is it normal? or should I give the value of the `surcharge` to the decimal?

Comment: easiest would be to cast to float `float(self.reg_price)`, but you should read up on python decimal to make sure your use case will not fall within the edge cases.

Comment: if i try :                                                                                        
`@property
def current_price(self):
       return self.reg_price`                                                                              i also can not see   `<td>{{ item.current_price }}</td>` - it is empty. But `<td>{{ item.reg_price }}</td>` not empty.

Comment: Hm, very strange. And what happens if you remove the @property decorator to make it a simple function? (The template code doesn't have to be changed). Besides that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You were right. I have a mistake with float and decimal when i use (print).                                                                                                      `TypeError at /search/

unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Decimal' and 'float'`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it on:

```
@property
def current_price(self):
     surcharge = 0
     self.reg_price = float(self.reg_price)



    if ((self.reg_price is None) or (self.reg_price == 0)):
        return surcharge

    if (self.reg_price < 50):
        surcharge = (0.1 * self.reg_price + self.reg_price) * 0.1173 + (0.1 * self.reg_price + self.reg_price) * 0.246

    elif (50 <= self.reg_price <= 500):
        surcharge = (0.1 * self.reg_price + self.reg_price) * 0.12 + (0.1 * self.reg_price + self.reg_price) * 0.249

    elif (self.reg_price > 500):
        surcharge = (0.1 * self.reg_price + self.reg_price) * 0.1175 + (0.1 * self.reg_price + self.reg_price) * 0.243

    return Decimal(self.reg_price + surcharge).quantize(Decimal('.00'), ROUND_FLOOR)
```

it is working!

But i have a mistake, when I try to select, the object is missing in the database.:

```
 AttributeError at /search/

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current_price'
```

Then i fix code on :

```
if reg_price:
    @property
    def current_price(self):
```

But it not work and i also have the same mistake.

How i can fix it?

Comment: Don't ask more questions in your answer. Post a new question instead.